# PHP 'loop for' with input text form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm doing a program  that I have to insert a number ("X"), and this will generate "X" number of "input forms" to enter diferent numbers to later, calculate some operations.

I have to generate the forms using **for**, and then, pass the results with a submit button with $_POST to the next page. Then, when I try to get the results with another **for**, it doesn't works and I get some problems.

**Notice: Undefined variable: num4 in...**

What Am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
<?php
/*HERE I GET THE NUMBER TO CREATE "X" NUMBER OF FORMS*/

if (isset($_POST["num"]))
{   
$num=$_POST["num"];
$_POST["num"]=$num;

        if ( is_numeric($num) and $num>=0)
        {
           echo"<form action=\"tercera.php\" method=\"post\">"; 
            echo "Quina operació vols fer?:<br><br> "
                . "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"operacio\" value=\"suma\"/>Suma "
                . "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"operacio\" value=\"mitja\"/>Mitja"
                . "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"operacio\" value=\"major\"/>Major"
                . "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"operacio\" value=\"menor\"/>Menor</p>";


/*HERE I MAKE THE FOR LOOP TO GENERATE THE FORMS WITH "numero[$i]" */

            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)
            {
               echo" <input type=\'text\' name=\'numero[$i]\' maxlength=\'10\' size=\"10\"/>"; 

            }
            echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Calcula' /></p>";               
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<H3>Has d'escriure un numero mes gran que 0, torna-ho a intentar.";
        }
}//isset*/

?>

/*/ NEXT  PHP PAGE /*/

<?php

if (isset($_POST["operacio"])) $operacio=$_POST["operacio"];

//HERE I GET THE NUMBERS OF THE LAST PAGE

   for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++)
   {
       if (isset($_POST["numero[$i]"])) $num2=$_POST["numero[$i]"] ;


//HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR: Undefined variable: num2  

        echo $num2;       
    }


//this part is ok ...

        if ($operacio == "suma") 
        {
            echo "i equals 0";
        }

        elseif ($operacio == "mitja") 
        {
            echo "i equals 1";
        }
        elseif ($operacio == "major") 
        {
            echo "i equals 2";
        }

        elseif ($operacio == "menor") 
        {
            echo "i equals 3";
        }


        if ( is_numeric($num) and $num>=0)
        {

            for ($i=1; $i<=$num; $i++)
            {


            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<H3>Has d'escriure un numero mes gran que 0, torna-ho a intentar.";
        }
//isset*/

?>
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: num4 in...` - the rest of the error message might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second page don't use this:

```
if (isset($_POST["numero[$i]"])) $num2=$_POST["numero[$i]"];
```

Because that field doesn't exist. When you use array of fields, what you need to do is get the field, and after that get the position, for instance, it could work:

```
if(isset($_POST["numero"]) && isset($_POST["numero"][$i])) $num2=$_POST["numero"][$i];
```

Remember, you are using a field that is an array.

If you don't want get in troubles with the elements in array, use it (after knowing that $_POST["numero] exists):

```
foreach($_POST["numero"] as $num)
{
    echo $num; // or waht you want to do.
}
```

I hope this help you.